# Android button border

Tags: android, android-button

I want to implement custom border for my android button.
I already research info about implementing this but didn't find anything.
I want to create button like this.

[image]

Have you any ideas how can we achieve this?
Can we do this thing with shapes, or we should crete file for different dpi(mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi)?

Comment: Have you tries defining a shape with border in the drawables and then accessing it by `button.setBackground(getResources(R.drawable.myButton));` ?

Comment: @ManuToMatic, i can't imagine what kind of shape i should use to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml layout (custom border) to create that shape,(in my opinion is not posible), but you can create a image like that(photoshop, gimp,etc.) and set the button background image.

```
android:background="@drawable/your_custom_image.png"
```

Comment: I have to create .png files for every dpi for correctly displaying on devices with different dpi?

Comment: Yes, for different resolutions (if you want to follow the best practice) but I think you sould try first to create a button with a high resolution and use it also for low resolutions and see how It would look

Comment: If you create a low res image on high res the button will look like dots on the screen:)

Comment: or you can also try to use a 9patch image:)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and later if everything will go fine accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom button using this xml. This xml will give you a round shape button. Try like this.
Make a xml like this one.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <shape 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <stroke 
      android:width="1dp" 
      android:color="#505050"/>
   <corners 
      android:radius="7dp" />

   <padding 
      android:left="1dp"
      android:right="1dp"
      android:top="1dp"
      android:bottom="1dp"/>

  <solid android:color="#505050"/>
```

And then use the file name of above xml into **android:background**